# clean() method in form not working (loading it into ListView)

Tags: django, listview, django-views, django-forms, django-queryset

I've tried searching around and reading the docs but I don't quite understand how to get the clean() method to work when dealing with ListView's, get_querysets() and get methods.

I've tried adding in a breakpoint() in the clean() method and it doesn't get triggered meaning it's not called at all.

My suspicion is because I'm not using post as the method in the form but I need to use get in order to build a filter query to a query set (namely, it's a date picker using from and to).

This is my setup (omitting details):

Form:

```
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
   ...
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        ...
        return self.cleaned_data
```

ListView:

```
class ReportView(ListView):
    form_class = ReportForm


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = kwargs.get('form', self.form_class())
        context['form'] = form
        return context
 
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Details omitted but I'm essentially taking data from the form 
        # and using it to filter a QuerySet

        from_date = self.request.GET.get('from_date')
        to_date = self.request.GET.get('to_date')

        .......

        return QuerySet
```

Template:

```
   <form action="" method="get">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {% crispy form %}
   </form>
```

Does anyone know why my clean method isn't being called?

Comment: Why would ListView implementation call clean on your form on anything regarding form, look into documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/ |
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: it ended up just being how I captured the form when I made the get request, I put the answer in this post. Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the way I was setting the form variable in `get_context_data()` was wrong.

(I didn’t bind the data to the form)

This solved my problem:

```
form = ReportForm(self.request.GET)
```